# How to open lightning component tab from lightning quick action instead of lightning modal?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning, tab, modal

I have build a simple lightning component something like :

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:lightningQuickAction">
   Hello World
</aura:component>
```

I have added a lightning action for this page on record home page, let say to be on "Account"

Whenever I click on that lightning action from any account record, it open lightning component in lightning modal. Is there any way to redirect user to standalone "lightning tab" like page instead of lightning modal?

Comment: Why not use a "custom button" with "content source"=URL instead (if all you want is to open a different page)?

Comment: I have tried that approach too, Using this way, I am not able to pass recordId to lightning component

Comment: Why not? which page are you trying to open? can you post the code you have tried with?

Comment: I might not be able to post complete code as its too big and convulated. But I can give you the gist of the issue
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:lightningQuickAction">
   <aura:attribute name="id" type="Id"/>
</aura:component>
In js controller logic, I need to access this id attribute to fetch data from apex controller.
Button url is something like
/c/mycomp.cmp?id=a00N000000G8bvEIAR
The issue is that I am unable to access this id in js controller of lightning component

Comment: Will I be able to use URL custom button on salesforce1?

Comment: Why do you need to send the id in the querystring? you can use the `force:hasRecordId` interface with `<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />` see [this page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_record_home.htm)

Comment: Issue is that if I use recordId, then the lightning component must be opened through lightning quick action button. In which case, it opens in a Model. The use case for this lightning component/page requires it to be in standalone page not in Model.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to open the lightning component in as a tab instead of the popup by using a small component which will redirect to the main component.

You can use the force:navigateToComponent event on init to navigate to your main component.

Comment: i tried using navigateToComponent and it's opening in a tab but the same screen. How did you manage to open in a new tab instead?

Answer (score 1):

**Component**

```
<aura:component 
    implements="force:appHostable, flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes, flexipage:availableForRecordHome, force:hasRecordId, forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes, force:lightningQuickAction">
    <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.navigateToeDiscoverySearchCmp}" value="{!this}" />
</aura:component>
```

**Controller**

```
({
    navigateToeDiscoverySearchCmp : function(component, event, helper) {
        var evt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent");
        evt.setParams({
            componentDef : "c:eDiscoverySearchCmp",
        });
        evt.fire();
    } 
})
```

Comment: We can also add attributes like : 
componentAttributes: {
            contactName : component.get("v.contact.Name")
        }